# Apps are opening on different apps icon in the toolbar

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons

Sometimes on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS laptop (GNOME 3.36.3 with X11), when I try to open a specific app it will open under a different application in the toolbar. For example here's a screenshot of my current toolbar:

[image: First Screenshot]

I have 2 Chrome windows open, but they both are opened as new 'Slack' windows.
When pressing the Chrome button in the toolbar, another window will open under 'Slack':

[image: Second Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. The only solution I have is opening Chrome first and then using the Slack app. If I do it in the reversed order nothing will fix it besides a restart...

Comment: absolutely bizarre. Couldn't find a solution to this day.

Comment: it makes me mad